# symfony fos user parameter listerner injection fail

Tags: symfony, parameters, listener

I'm using FOSUserBundle to manage users. I needed to rewrite the listener related to this event. The latter is defined with dependencies as follows:

```
    user.password.change:
        class: AppBundle\Listeners\PasswordResettingListener
        arguments: ['@router', '@listener1', '@listener2']
        tags:
           - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

My problem lies in the injection of dependency parameters. Listener 2 depends on another listener:

```
    listener2:
        class: AppBundle\HTTPRequest\Rezopouce
        arguments: ["@request_stack", '@api.token.listener']

    api.token.listener:
        class: AppBundle\Listeners\ApiTokenListener
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@security.token_storage', '%api%']
        tags:
             - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

One of the dependencies, api.token.listener: '% api%' is an array of parameters defined in the configuration. It is this dependency that is not properly injected.

I would like to point out that when the listener is called directly after the event kernel.request, the dependency is injected without any problem.

The constructor for the api.token.listener where `$api` is a protected attibute:

```
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, TokenStorageInterface $security_token_storage, $api = null) { ...
```

I don't understand the problem's origin.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages and what version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: I throw an exception when `$ api === null` otherwise I have nothing at all. I can not connect to my API because I do not have the settings but the code runs normally.

Comment: Symfony 3.4.6
FOSUserBundle 2

Comment: So no actual errors, just not getting any value for api?  Start by taking out the = null portion since $api has to have values.  This shoud trigger an error which might help.  I suspect autowire/autoconfigure might be to blame.  Are they enabled?

Comment: And consider making ApiTokenListener a subscriber like you did with PasswordResettingListener.  I don't think it will make a difference but maybe it impacts the order in which the listeners are created.  And you might need to set the priority to ensure ApiTokenListener kicks off first.

Comment: While typing the previous comment I realized that injecting listeners into other listeners makes no sense at all.  Use the priority to control the order in which listeners are executed.  If you need to pass some data from one listener to another then store the data in the $request->attributes bag.

Comment: Okay. I will explore these directions and come back here to follow up even in case of resolution.